# __init__() is missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, initialization

```
    class Blaster(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, Range, accuracy):
        self.accuracy = accuracy
        self.Range = Range
        super()
blaster = Blaster(Weapon)
```

I am very new to Python and I'm making a game and using classes for the items. When I run this the error code is:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'accuracy'
```

I want to be able to use objects to hold information on different items, and for them to be printed out for the user.

Superclasses:

```
class Item():
def __init__(self, name, description, value):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.value = value

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, damage, speed):
        self.damage = damage
        self.speed = speed
        super()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of a class yo need to provide the parameters (except for the `self`) of the `__init__` function:

```
class Blaster():
    def __init__(self, Range, accuracy):
        self.accuracy = accuracy
        self.Range = Range

blaster_range = 50
blaster_accunary = 0.5
blaster = Blaster(blaster_range, blaster_accunary)
```

Of course you can also do this, I used variables to make clear what's the meaning of the values.

```
blaster = Blaster(50, 0.5)
```

And for inheritance, you need to pass all the parameters all the way down like this ([See Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/b3ee2049-096a-47da-bb9e-1783c6e46f4e)):

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, description, value):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.value = value

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, value, damage, speed):
        self.damage = damage
        self.speed = speed
        Item.__init__(self, name, description, value)

class Blaster(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, description, value, damage, speed, Range, accuracy):
        self.accuracy = accuracy
        self.Range = Range
        Weapon.__init__(self, name, description, value, damage, speed)

blaster = Blaster(
    name="MyBlaster",
    description="A huge weapon",
    value=10,
    damage=20,
    speed=30,
    Range=50,
    accuracy=0.5
)
print(blaster.name)
print(blaster.description)
print(blaster.value)
print(blaster.damage)
print(blaster.speed)
print(blaster.Range)
print(blaster.accuracy)
```

If all Blasters have a fixed (e.g.) damage and speed, then you can do this;

```
...

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, value, damage, speed):
        self.damage = damage
        self.speed = speed
        Item.__init__(self, name, description, value)

class Blaster(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, description, value, Range, accuracy):
        self.accuracy = accuracy
        self.Range = Range

        blasters_damage = 20
        blasters_speed = 30
        Weapon.__init__(self, name, description, value, blasters_damage , blasters_speed)

blaster = Blaster(
    name="MyBlaster",
    description="A huge weapon",
    value=10,
    Range=50,
    accuracy=0.5
)

...
```